# postgres : Update rows but ignore those which on update violate a unique constraint

Tags: postgresql, sql-update

I am updating a table which has 4 columns together as primary key.

```
|Col1|Col2|Col3|Col4|val|
|   1|   2|   3|   4|234|
```

Col 1-4 make primary key

I need to update Col1 in some rows. But some rows already have the value which i want to update. Thus when i run the query it gives :

```
ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "datavalue_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4)=(609, 76911, 164, 1) already exists.
```

How can i ignore the cases which are already present so that update query runs fully??

Update Query :

```
update datavalue dv set Col1 = 6009
where concat( dv.Col1 ,'-',dv.Col2,'-',Col3,'-',dv.Col4) 
in (
     Select concatenated id ... from same table
   )
```

Thanks

POSTGRES - 9.5.12

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add the `update` statement you are using.

Comment: Can you be more detailed about the UPDATE statement? Is the subselect an attempt to solve the problem or is it the way to determine which rows should be updated?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on your application, I would suggest to write a function, but I guess what you're looking for is something like this (quick & dirty):

Test table and dataset:

```
CREATE TEMP TABLE t (id INT UNIQUE, des TEXT);
INSERT INTO t VALUES (1,'foo'),(2,'bar');
```

Update ignoring conflicts.

```
DO $$
DECLARE r RECORD;
BEGIN
  FOR r IN SELECT * FROM t  LOOP 
    BEGIN          

      UPDATE t SET id = 2 WHERE des = 'foo' AND id = r.id;
      UPDATE t SET des = 'bar2' WHERE id = 2 AND id = r.id;  

      EXCEPTION WHEN unique_violation THEN
        RAISE NOTICE 'Oups .. there was a conflict on % - %',r.id,r.des;
    END;    
    END LOOP;

END$$;
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your example correctly, you should be able to use a subquery to simply exclude rows with the Col1 value you are trying to set.

```
UPDATE datavalue SET Col1 = '6009'
WHERE [your conditions]
AND Col1 NOT IN (SELECT Col1 FROM datavalue WHERE Col1 = '6009')
```